# Using updating a linear model with lagged new variables

Tags: r

I have a base model `y ~ x1 + x2`.

I want to update the model to contain `y ~ x1 + x2 + lag(x3, 2) + lag(x4, 2)`.

x3 and x4 are also dynamically selected.

```
fmla <- as.formula(paste('.~.', paste(c(x3, x4), collapse = '+')))
```

My update formula: `update(fit, fmla)`

I get a error saying x3/x4 is not found from the as.formula function.  I understand the error just not how to get around to what I want to do.

Comment: what do you mean by "x3 and x4 are also dynamically selected." Are they variables declared in your code? Do you wanna paste their names or their values?

Comment: Not sure but you might also have an issue with calling `lag` inside your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution for your problem can be:

```
# Data generating process
yX <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000),ncol=5))
names(yX) <- c("y", paste("x",1:4,sep=""))

# Start with a linear model with x1 and x2 as explanatory variables
f1 <- as.formula(y ~ x1 + x2)
fit <- lm(f1, data=yX)

# Add lagged x3 and x4 variables
fmla <- as.formula(paste('~.+',paste("lag(",addvars,",2)", collapse = '+')))
update(fit,  fmla)

# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + lag(x3, 2) + lag(x4, 2), data = yX)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x1           x2   lag(x3, 2)   lag(x4, 2)  
#   -0.083180     0.015753     0.041998     0.000612    -0.093265
```

Below an example with the `dynlm` package.

```
data("USDistLag", package = "lmtest")

# Start with a dynamic linear model with gnp as explanatory variables
library(dynlm)
f1 <- as.formula(consumption ~ gnp)
( fit <- dynlm(f1, data=USDistLag) )

# Time series regression with "ts" data:
# Start = 1963, End = 1982
# 
# Call:
# dynlm(formula = f1, data = USDistLag)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          gnp  
#    -24.0889       0.6448

# Add lagged gnp 
addvars <- c("gnp")
fmla <- as.formula(paste('~.+',paste("lag(",addvars,",2)", collapse = '+')))
update(fit,  fmla)

# Time series regression with "ts" data:
# Start = 1963, End = 1980
# 
# Call:
# dynlm(formula = consumption ~ gnp + lag(gnp, 2), data = USDistLag)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          gnp  lag(gnp, 2)  
#    -31.1437       0.5366       0.1067
```

Comment: OP is calling `lag()`. Can you see if this works with `lag`?